# Will a primary key index serve as an index for a foreign key when fk columns are subset of pk?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, composite-primary-key

I have a table where part of the primary key is a foreign key to another table.

```
create table player_result (
  event_id        integer not null,
  pub_time        timestamp not null,
  name_key        varchar(128) not null,
  email_address   varchar(128),
  withdrawn       boolean not null,
  place           integer,
  realized_values hstore,
  primary key (event_id, pub_time, name_key),
  foreign key (email_address) references email(address),
  foreign key (event_id, pub_time) references event_publish(event_id, pub_time));
```

Will the index generated for the primary key suffice to back the foreign key on `event_id` and `pub_time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Index `A,B,C`

is good for:

`A`
`A,B`
`A,B,C` (and any other combination of the full 3 fields, *if* default order is unimportant)

but not good for other combinations (such as `B,C`, `C,A` etc.).

Answer (score 2):

It will be useful for the *referencing side*, such that a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` on the *referenced* table can use the `PRIMARY KEY` of the referencing side as an index when performing checks for the existence of referencing rows or running cascade update/deletes. PostgreSQL doesn't require this index to exist at all, it just makes foreign key constraint checks faster if it is there.

It is *not* sufficient to serve as the unique constraint for a *reference* to those columns. You couldn't create a `FOREIGN KEY` that `REFERENCES player_result(event_id, pub_time)` because there is no `unique` constraint on those columns. That pair can appear multiple times in the table so long as each pair has a different `name_key`.

As @xagyg accurately notes, the unique b-tree index created by the foreign key reference is also only useful for references to columns from the left of the index. It could not be used for a lookup of `pub_time, name_key` or just `name_key`, for example.